# Pass AngularJS data to Laravel generated URL

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm in the process of building a Laravel and AngularJS app. I use Angular to send HTTP GET requests to a Laravel route and obtain JSON data before writing it into HTML. I'm using Laravel for my routing as Angular is only present on a couple of pages.

My site has a list of jobs which are displayed, 5 at a time, via Angular. Next to the title of each job is an option to 'Send a Message'. The code in my view is like so:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="job in main.jobs">
        <a href="@{{ job.slug }}">@{{ job.title }}</a> -
        <a href="{{ URL::route('sendmessage', ["@{{ job.slug }}"]) }}">Send a Message</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The data renders perfectly however I cannot use the `URL::route` function with Angular to render the route URL with job.slug as the parameter.

My routes.php file looks like:

```
Route::get('jobs/{slug}/messages/create', [
    'as'   => 'sendmessage',
    'uses' => 'MessageController@create'
]);
```

Note as this is a blade file, I use the @ before the `{{ }}` to render Angular.

My exam question: How I can use blade to echo Angular data in the `URL::route` facade

Comment: no idea why you need server side templating and client side templating mixed together. Seems like a nightmare to maintain. Also not clear what your specific problem is

Comment: Have you tried using ng-href?

Comment: I think maintenance becomes an issue if you have not structured your app appropriately. I only want to use Angular on a couple of pages of my development site before I push to production in a few months time

Comment: you can accept my answer for further readers if it was helpful :)

Comment: @limonte - Sorry but it wasn't

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom AngularJS curly braces to prevent conflict with Blade template engine:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []) 

  .config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    // To prevent the conflict of `{{` and `}}` symbols
    // between Blade template engine and AngularJS templating we need
    // to use different symbols for AngularJS.

    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%=');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
  });
```

I suggest to use `<%= %>` because it's the often used construction, you can find it in [Underscore templates](http://underscorejs.org/).

After that your code will look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="job in main.jobs">
        <a href="<%= job.slug %>"><%= job.title %></a> -
        <a href="{{ URL::route('sendmessage', ["@{{ job.slug }}"]) }}">Send a Message</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For reference, the reverse is also possible. Meaning you can redefine the Blade tags as well, for example: `Blade::setEscapedContentTags('[[', ']]');` and `Blade::setContentTags('[!!', '!!]');`. But it seems obvious from the question that the best solution here is to change Angular template tags.

Comment: The issue isn't conflict. The issue is how can I echo out angular data using blade?

Comment: @BarryBlade you're doing wrong if you want to echo out angular data using blade. In other words you want to echo client-side data in back-end, this makes no sense to me.

Comment: @limonte - Nope. I just want Blade to ignore the data so Angular processes it